# Unable to link libraries when compiling native node modules to Android. Recompile with -fPIC issue when using -fPIC flag

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, node-gyp

This question is mostly related to node-gyp, GCC and the NDK toolchain, but I will add the full context because it may be necessary.

**Context**

I am building an App using React Native. Since I need to use node native libraries in this App, I am using this node module [nodejs-mobile](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile) for running a Node.js process on Android and iOS.

When adding the [composer-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/composer-admin) module, I am having compilation issues for Android.

**Error**

The compiler is failing when linking the `grpc_node` module which is required by a `composer-admin` dependency. The error is:

`[LIB 1 PATH OMITTED] requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
...
[LIB N PATH OMITTED] requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
clang70++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [grpc_node.target.mk:189: Release/obj.target/grpc_node.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/vanclief/Cacao_repos/react-app/android/build/nodejs-native-assets-temp-build/nodejs-native-assets-armeabi-v7a/nodejs-project/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/build'`

The weird thing is the `-fPIC` flag is being used as specified in the [common.gypi](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-react-native/blob/ed727edea17e8a9e1a85cef3413becc83b8a0328/android/libnode/include/node/common.gypi):

`/home/vanclief/Cacao_repos/react-app/android/build/standalone-toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang++ -shared -g -rdynamic -fPIC  -Wl,-soname=grpc_node.node -o`

[This is the full compilation log](https://gist.github.com/Vanclief/518de77b69aea8cca29e64bdb24c829e)

Comment: Are you done? Can you share a result gyp file?

Comment: Sorry, this issue was solved many years ago and I don't longer work in that project. It was just a matter of changing  `-fPIC` from `ldflags` to `cflags` as stated on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

common.gypi is wrong. It has `-fPIC` in ldflags. It needs to be in cflags.